# Gas furnace only lighting two of four burners

Tags: furnace, gas-burner

Good morning all,

Long story short I have had an issue with my furnace (a Payne PG8MA) that no one has been able to resolve for a few years. I can't remember exactly how long it has been happening, but I think our first year in the house was issue free. If so then we have been dealing with it for about five years or so now.

We have called in professionals at least 3 or 4 different times to help, but they only ever leave me with a bill and some advice to use some mesh wire to scrape this little hex screw thing that can get dirty/corroded from build up.

For some reason the igniter lights up, but when it tries to light only two of the four burners go.

Previously the only way to get the furnace to kick on was by restarting the furnace. To do this I would have to lower the temperature, turn off the furnace, wait a bit, turn it back on, wait a bit, and then turn up the temp to trigger it to start up again. This process could work right away or take an hour of attempts before it would finally go.

Yesterday I somehow discovered if I blow on it and give the flames more oxygen that it will kick up the flame and help it jump to the last two burners...

Am I going to blow up my furnace doing this?

I also found online during this morning's "searching for my own resolution sessions" something about it possibly being a gas pressure problem that it is not reaching all the burners as well as something about using a long neck lighter to get the last two to light...

I realize that is more than one question, but I am hoping they are related enough to not need to separate them. (If not please just let me know if I am going to blow up my home blowing on the burners!)

Thank you for any assistance!

And here is a picture of the furnace information that hopefully would be helpful:

[image]

Comment: Some additional information like make/model of the furnace, it's approx. age, and who has looked at it.

Comment: Is this a new problem? Can the igniter be adjusted?

Comment: @jwh20 - details added!

Comment: It's an 18 year-old furnace.  It could be past the end of its useful life.  Who exactly have you had look at it?  What it just nobody in particular or was it a qualified HVAC technician?

Comment: It is turbulence that causes the furnace to light when you blow on it. Some furnaces have a fine mesh or a tray above the burners at the back this gets knocked out with cleaning. The tray catches the gas and when it has enough to reach the lit burner it flashes back and starts the unlit burner. I have made them out of heavy tin foil folded over to show the owners, I can’t actually make a modification but this works for quite a while. I am guessing they did pull the burners and clean them since you have had several look at it. The foil or metal tray only takes about a second to lite the sides.

Comment: Thank you Ed, that is good to know. @jwh20 - I have basically just called local Plumbing and Heating guys. I don't know about their qualifications or anything, but I assume they know what they are doing! We called the 'popular' local company two or three times and tried one or two other companies a couple other times all with no avail. Still, none of them recommended we replace it as it still is working, though intermittently. Like I said, I am mostly just worried about it blowing up in my face when I blow on it! Until it fully dies assuming its safe I might just do that! Save money...